# how to make edge fade away with principled volume shader

Tags: shaders, volumetrics

how can i make edge on the atmosphere fade onto nothingness, right now it is to noticeable where it ends. I am using only principled volume shader and the density is at 0.0003. Changing density does not change edge sharpness. blender 2.8, cycles
[image]